# Configuration for exec-maven-plugin to work with AOP's aspectjweaver (javaagent)

Tags: maven, maven-3, aop, aspectj, javaagents

Working with Maven 3.6.3.

For a simple Java app, about AspectJ and JUnit, I have the following dependencies:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Where

```
<aspectj.version>1.9.6</aspectj.version>
<junit.version>5.6.2</junit.version>
```

I have the following plugin:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.surefire.plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <argLine>
                -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/.../aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
            </argLine>
            <useSystemClassLoader>true</useSystemClassLoader>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Where `<maven.surefire.plugin.version>2.22.2</maven.surefire.plugin.version>`

Until here AOP works fine only for Testing, therefore:

- `@Aspect` and `@Pointcut` are well configured and work fine at runtime in Testing
- `META-INF/aop.xml` is well configured too

Just in case:

```
<aspectj>
    <aspects>
        <aspect name="com.manuel.jordan.aop.CalculatorAspect"/>
         <weaver options="-verbose -showWeaveInfo">
            <include within="*"/>
        </weaver>
    </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

The point is: for the `Main` execution, AOP does not work, it because `maven-surefire-plugin` is for testing. Therefore the following plugin is added:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${exec.maven.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <executable>java</executable>
        <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
        <arguments>
            <argument>-javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/.../aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Where `<exec.maven.plugin.version>3.0.0</exec.maven.plugin.version>`

**Note:** `javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/.../aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar` are the same path for both plugins. Remember for the first plugin it works fine. So the path is correct.

The `Main` class runs and is executed in peace but the problem is that AOP is not applied. Therefore because AOP in Testing works, what is the missing configuration in `exec-maven-plugin`? I read many *SO's* posts and playing around through the configurations shared and nothing.

### Update

If I execute in the Terminal:

```
java -javaagent:pathtotheaspectjweaverjar.jar 
     -cp ./target/classes 
     com.manuel.jordan.Main
```

It works fine, AOP is working how is expected.

After to did do a research is **mandatory** have the `-javaagent:pathtotheaspectjweaverjar.jar` parameter before the `-cp` parameter.

**Current Problem Scenario:** therefore through the `Main` class and its `(String[] args)` parameter I confirmed that with the *current plugin configuration* the `-javaagent:pathtotheaspectjweaverjar.jar` parameter is interpreted how a simple *Program parameter*

Practically as follows:

```
java -cp ./target/classes 
     com.manuel.jordan.Main
     -javaagent:pathtotheaspectjweaverjar.jar <-- how a program argument parameter
```

So, how configure the plugin to accomplish the same goal how the former command execution?

Comment: Manuel, is there any chance you can publish a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub? I would like to build your project (or a smaller, anonymised version of it reproducing the problem) myself. The reason can be all sorts of things: agent parameter not being used, agent loaded but no aspects found and a few more. I need more details and see for myself in order to help you fix that.

Comment: hello @kriegaex see the `Update` section. Thanks for the comment

Comment: Thanks for the update, Manuel. This is certainly helpful, but I really don't want to recreate your whole setup from scratch, filling in the missing parts. So I am repeating my request for an MCVE. If I had one, your problem possibly would be solved already.